# How to use JavaScript result as PHP tag?

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating this sort of event table. I want to display the event time on the website in the user's timezone. I feel like I am 1 step away from the result as I already found out how to change the saved unix timestamp to another timezone, and I found out how to fetch the user's timezone.

My PHP code looks like this (this is part of the script)

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $TimeZoneHere = **Script to fetch timezone**
    date_default_timezone_set($TimeZoneHere);
    $dtstamp = date('d M', $row["timestamp"]);
    $ttstamp = date('H:i', $row["timestamp"]);
```

And my JavaScript line to fetch timezone would be `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`

I hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

I tried putting SCRIPT in the PHP tag but that did not work, it gave me a HTTP 500 error. I tried ending the php tag and starting php tag with the script in between, gave me an error also. No one online seems to have a similar issue.

Comment: Php runs on the server before the page is loaded into the browser. Javascript runs in the browser _after_ the page has loaded. So you can't put the result of a Javascript function directly into a php script...all you'll get is the raw Javascript code as a string, because it won't be able to execute before the php does.

Comment: You could potentially get the user's timezone from the browser when they first visit the application and send it to the server, then store it in the Session to use later. Or you could just let php output the server time and have JS convert it to local time as soon as the page containing the time data has loaded into the browser